# How to set up online database for java netbeans application

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

i'm trying a online database connection for my java application, but it seems my database isn't connected well this is my java code :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("sql101.epizy.com/epiz_26206530_sekolah","LOGIN","PASSWORD");
        String query = "select * from users where username=? and password=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jPasswordField1.getText());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Berhasil");
            jLabel7.setText(rs.getString(1));
            welcome well = new welcome();
            this.setVisible(false);
            well.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

i already input MySQL JDBC Driver library, by the way i'm using online database from https://infinityfree.net/

Comment: You are likely getting an Exception, but you are ignoring the details. Use `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block to print details. You should also not post your login details here...

Comment: it says "no suitable driver found", do you know what is the right driver for this issue?

Comment: you need to put `jdbc:mysql://` at the beginning of your connection url

Comment: there is another error says "communication link failed 
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."